# Flex items dont shrink equally when padding is add to one of them

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.flex-item {
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}
.flex-item-1 {
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-item-2 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(15, 36, 221);
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
  </div>
```

Flex items dont shrink equally when padding is add to one of them no matter what you do.
Is it possible to make items grow equally or shrink equally if one of them have padding?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` and remove that margin ? If you want a gap change to `flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);` and use `gap` on parent

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in beatifully written articles on css tricks - https://css-tricks.com/equal-columns-with-flexbox-its-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

The conclusion is - padding and borders of flex items do not participate in flex-grow or flex-shrink calculations and act as they were taking space outside of those items.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid in this case

```css
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(15, 36, 221);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-1"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well thats a cheatcode :3